# Need help in ls -ltr linux bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to list the last 3 logs in a specific folder and redirect the output to another tmp.out file.

```
ls -ltr /home/oracle/$dbserver/*.log  |  awk '{print $9}' | tail -3   | tee tmp.out
```

What I expect to see in the tmp file is:

```
a.out
b.out
c.out
```

What I get instead is:

```
/home/oracle/DB1/a.out
/home/oracle/DB1/b.out
/home/oracle/DB1/c.out
```

I definitely need to use something between tail and tee. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls -ltr /home/oracle.$dbserver/*.log | tail -3 | awk '{print $NF}' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | tee tmp.out
```

Comment: You mean `tail -3`, not `tail - 3`.

Answer (score 1):

Jut `cd` to that directory and then

```
 cd /home/oracle/$dbserver/ && ls -ltr *.log  |  awk '{print $9}' | tail -3   | tee  $OLDPWD/tmp.out
```

Answer (score 1):

the `basename` command will take a string of the form `/foo/bar/baz.txt` and return simply `baz.txt`.  Invoke it via xargs, making sure to use the command-line flag `-n 1` so it only sends one filename at a time to `basename`.

`ls -ltr /home/oracle/$dbserver/*.log  |  awk '{print $9}' | xargs -n 1 basename | tail -3   | tee tmp.out`